# How to add new column group after using pivot pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I'm trying to create a new column group consisting of 3 sub-columns after using `pivot` on a dataframe, but the result is only one column.

Let's say I have the following dataframe that I pivot:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': ['one', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'two',
                           'two'],
                   'bar': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
                   'baz': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                   'zoo': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})
df.pivot(index='foo', columns='bar', values=['baz', 'zoo'])
```

Now I want an extra column group that is the sum of the two value columns *baz* and *zoo*.

My output:

```
df.loc[:, "baz+zoo"] = df.loc[:,'baz'] + df.loc[:,'baz']
```

[image: My output]

The desired output:

[image]

I know that performing the sum and then concatenating will do the trick, but I was hoping for a neater solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if many rows or mainly many columns is better/faster create new `DataFrame` and add first level of `MultiIndex` by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) and add to original by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df1 = df.loc[:,'baz'] + df.loc[:,'zoo']
df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['baz+zoo'], df1.columns])
print (df1)
   baz+zoo        
          A   B   C
foo                
one       2   4   6
two       8  10  12

df = df.join(df1)
print (df)
    baz       zoo       baz+zoo        
bar   A  B  C   A  B  C       A   B   C
foo                                    
one   1  2  3   1  2  3       2   4   6
two   4  5  6   4  5  6       8  10  12
```

Another solution is loop by second levels and select `MultiIndex` by tuples, but if large DataFrame performance should be worse, the best test with real data:

```
for x in df.columns.levels[1]:
    df[('baz+zoo', x)] = df[('baz', x)] + df[('zoo', x)]
print (df)
    baz       zoo       baz+zoo        
bar   A  B  C   A  B  C       A   B   C
foo                                    
one   1  2  3   1  2  3       2   4   6
two   4  5  6   4  5  6       8  10  12
```

Comment: The latter one already looks a lot better than my solution, thanks! I hoped for a solution that performs the columns sum all at once without looping over individual columns.

Comment: @Michieldo -Ya, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it this way too. I'm not sure I understand the theory, but...

```
df['baz+zoo'] = df['baz']+df['zoo']
df.pivot(index='foo', columns='bar', values=['baz','zoo','baz+zoo'])
```

Comment: That is neat, but if I would like to perform and action of some type after pivoting I need to unpivot again, perform that action on the dataframe like you proposed and then pivot again on the new dataframe?

Comment: First, you can combine 'baz' and 'zoo' and then run pivot to achieve it. The first 'pivot' is not executed.